# Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system when trying to run from a docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

```
Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
api_1  | Expected directory: node-v72-linux-x64-musl
api_1  | Found: [node-v64-linux-x64-glibc, node-v72-linux-x64-glibc, node-v83-linux-x64-glibc]
api_1  | This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system
api_1  | Original error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-linux-x64-musl/grpc_node.node'
api_1  | Require stack:
api_1  | - /usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js
api_1  | - /usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js
api_1  | - /usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js
api_1  | - /usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/index.js
api_1  | - /usr/src/app/middleware/license.js
api_1  | - /usr/src/app/app.js
api_1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js:53:17)
api_1  |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
api_1  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
api_1  |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
api_1  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
api_1  |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
api_1  |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
api_1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:144:12)
api_1  |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
api_1  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
api_1  |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
api_1  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
api_1  |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
api_1  |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
api_1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:35:27)
api_1  |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30) {
api_1  |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
api_1  | }
```

i am trying to run from inside a docker container i tried changing the node version but still cant solve it i tried node v 12 and 14

Comment: Since you are trying to run it in docker. There must be some mismatch with your os and the base image you are using in docker.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem, this fixed it

```
npm install --target=12.0.0 --target_platform=linux --target_arch=x64 --target_libc=musl
```